# Rocket-chip instruction trace columns

Tags: riscv, rocket-chip

When I run `make run-asm-tests` in the `emulator` directory of rocket-chip, I get a bunch of `*.out` files in the `emulator/output` directory. These appear to be instruction traces but the columns are not labeled. I was wondering what each of these columns means. Thanks!

For Example:

```
C0:      82212 [0] pc=[000000081c] W[r 0=0000000000000400][0] R[r 8=0000000000000000] R[r 0=0000000000000000] inst=[40044403] lbu     s0, 1024(s0)
C0:      82213 [0] pc=[000000081c] W[r 0=0000000000000400][0] R[r 8=0000000000000000] R[r 0=0000000000000000] inst=[40044403] lbu     s0, 1024(s0)
C0:      82214 [1] pc=[0000000820] W[r 8=0000000000000000][1] R[r 8=0000000000000000] R[r 3=0000000000000003] inst=[00347413] andi    s0, s0, 3
C0:      82215 [1] pc=[0000000824] W[r 0=0000000000000000][0] R[r 8=0000000000000000] R[r 0=0000000000000000] inst=[fe0408e3] beqz    s0, pc - 16
C0:      82216 [1] pc=[0000000814] W[r 8=0000000000000000][1] R[r 0=0000000000000000] R[r20=0000000000000003] inst=[f1402473] csrr    s0, mhartid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first column `C0:` stands for core 0. If you have multiple cores each will print its own trace prefixed with its `hartid`.

The second column `82212` through `82216` is the current cycle number.

The third column `[0]` or `[1]` shows whether this instruction committed this cycle (i.e. finished without exceptions).

The fourth column `pc=[...]` shows the current program counter value.

The fifth column `W[r 8=...][1]` shows the destination register of the current instruction in the suffix of the `r`, the value being written to that register after the `=`, and whether this write is happening in the `[0]` or `[1]`.

The sixth column `R[r 8=...]` shows the the first source register's index in the suffix of the `'r` and the value read from that register after the `=`.

The seventh column is the same as the sixth but for the second source register.

The eighth column `inst=[...]` shows the bits in the current instruction.

The ninth and final column shows a disassembly of the current instruction.